# java.util.Collections.swap(List<?> list, int i, int j) do nothing

Tags: java, spring, jpa, entitymanager

I have a Java Spring MVC and one of my models is Category

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Category extends AuditModel {
    @JsonView(DataTablesOutput.View.class)
    String name;
    boolean active;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    String description;
    @Column(length = 70)
    String metaTitle;
    @Column(length = 160)
    String metaDescription;
    String friendlyUrl;
    @OneToMany
    List<Category> secondaryCategories;
    String image;
    Long position;
}
```

I try to swap positions of two Categories in the secondaryCategories list with java.util.Collections.swap(List list, int i, int j) but nothing happens, no errors too.

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity moveCategoryUpOrDown(Long id, Long parentId, String direction) {
    if (id == parentId) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Home category cat't be moved",HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    Category category = categoryRepository.findOne(id);
    Category parent = categoryRepository.findOne(parentId);
    List<Category> secondaryCategories = parent.getSecondaryCategories();
    if (direction.compareTo("up") == 0) {
        if (secondaryCategories.indexOf(category) <= 0)
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        int i = secondaryCategories.indexOf(category);
        int j = secondaryCategories.indexOf(category) - 1;
//            Category previous = secondaryCategories.get(j);
        Collections.swap(secondaryCategories, i, j);
//            categoryRepository.saveAndFlush(previous);
//            categoryRepository.saveAndFlush(category);
        categoryRepository.saveAndFlush(parent);
    }
... etc ..
```

I also tried EntityManager detach the objects before swaping with no success. I made my own swap method but I wasn't able to swap.

How can I swap two Categories in secondaryCategories?

Comment: You did *nothing* with the entities, you save them, and expect them to  change...

Comment: How is that List ordered? If you don't put `@OrderBy` or `@OrderColumn` then the ordering is by the id of the element. So "swapping" will do nothing in terms of what is in the datastore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update their `position` fields, or whatever that sets the ordering of the entity. Changing the order of the collection means nothing from the point of view of the ORM.

Comment: I updated the position fields but inside the secondaryCategories the order is not changed and my secondary categories are listed same as before because of that.

Comment: You can add `@OrderBy` on your entity. It should do it